# Adding rows to a DataFrame column that doesn't exist yet

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a string that I have in a specific column of a DataFrame, get the numbers from the two new series, and assign the values to four new columns.

Before any modification the "Score" column on Saison looks like this:

```
0    \n3:2 (1:1) \n
1    \n0:2 (0:2) \n
2    \n1:1 (1:0) \n
3    \n1:1 (1:1) \n
4    \n2:0 (2:0) \n
```

The output that I want is this:

```
  Tore_Heim Tore_Auswärts Tore_Heim_HZ Tore_Auswärts_HZ
0         3             2            1                1
1         0             2            0                2
2         1             1            1                0
3         1             1            1                1
4         2             0            2                0
```

I have found a solution using list comprehension like this:

```
scores["Tore_Heim"] = pd.DataFrame([re.findall("\d+", scores[0][i]) for i in range(len(scores))]).loc[:, 0]
scores["Tore_Auswärts"] = pd.DataFrame([re.findall("\d+", scores[0][i]) for i in range(len(scores))]).loc[:, 1]
scores["Tore_Heim_HZ"] = pd.DataFrame([re.findall("\d+", scores[1][i]) for i in range(len(scores))]).loc[:, 0]
scores["Tore_Auswärts_HZ"] = pd.DataFrame([re.findall("\d+", scores[1][i]) for i in range(len(scores))]).loc[:, 1]
```

A second question is whether line 2 and 3 could be combined into one.

Comment: Where is your data and expected output?

Comment: Actually, my solution has the problem that it assigns a list of strings to the column, not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.extractall` + `unstack`:

```
df
              Col
0  \n3:2 (1:1) \n
1  \n0:2 (0:2) \n
2  \n1:1 (1:0) \n
3  \n1:1 (1:1) \n
4  \n2:0 (2:0) \n

v = df.Col.str.extractall('(\d+)', flags=re.M).unstack()
v.columns = ['Tore_Heim', 'Tore_Auswärts', 'Tore_Heim_HZ', 'Tore_Auswärts_HZ']
v

  Tore_Heim Tore_Auswärts Tore_Heim_HZ Tore_Auswärts_HZ
0         3             2            1                1
1         0             2            0                2
2         1             1            1                0
3         1             1            1                1
4         2             0            2                0
```

To convert to numeric type, apply `pd.to_numeric` accross columns -

```
v = v.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Or, perform an `astype` conversion -

```
v = v.astype(float) # .astype(int) will work if you don't have NaNs in your data
```

Comment: That's great thanks a lot! So much shorter. Two questions: what does `flag=re.M` do and how do I get the output as integers instead of string?

Comment: @iuvbio Multiline match, because you seem to have newlines in your data, so the flag is needed to match across multiple newlines. Also, I've already addressed that with a subsequent edit.